# How do I fix videos not loading when I have high internet speeds?

Tags: video, internet-connection, gigabit-ethernet

For the past 2 to 3 weeks I cannot watch videos on the internet on my computer. Whether its YouTube, Netflix, or even loading the videos on Pinterest. I downloaded Cloudflare's 1.1.1.1 and that seemed to fix it for a couple of days, but after that it just stopped working again. I am connected with ethernet on my computer, and its only happening to my computer. Wi-Fi is working fine. My upload and download speeds are **4 ping, 881mpbs download, 941mpbs upload**.

Comment: What device are you using? What operating system? Is your device working if you use wifi and not ethernet? How did you test the speeds?

Comment: I'm using a custom built computer. Specs are i7-11700KF , RTX 3060 , MOBO is B560-PLUS , 16gb @ 3200mhz ram. Videos do load when I use wifi on my computer, but i prefer using ethernet for better ping and better upload / download. I tested the speeds with speedtest.net

Comment: "I downloaded Cloudflare's 1.1.1.1?" You mean use that for DNS lookup? What happens when trying to play a video -- nothing? slow loading? DRM warnings?

Comment: Cloudflare has an app that like changes your dns or something idk really but it stopped working. When I play a video it loads like 2 seconds and then it doesnt load anymore even if I wait ten minutes it still doesnt load